# C++ do/while loop with two different conditions

Tags: c++

I want the *do while* loop to check to see if the entered input is R *OR* P. I think it is checking for both and when I get to that part when I run, it pauses for a minute and then I get "CPU Limit Exceeded (core dumped). On another related note, am I in danger of breaking something?

```
/************************************************/
/* Name: servcode                               */
/* Description: Get service type                */
/* Parameters: N/A                              */
/* Return Value: servcode                       */
/************************************************/

char servcode()
{
  char servcode = 'a';   // Define variable for service code
  char serviceyn = 'n';  // Define variable for user verify
  int i = 1;             // Define variable for sentinel loop

  do {
    cout << "\n" << "\n" << "Please enter your service code, [R]egular or [P]remium: " << "\n";
    cin >> servcode;
    while ((servcode != 'R', 'P') && (i < 3));
    {
        cout << "\n" << "Error - invalid service code, please try again.";
        cout << "\n" << "Please enter your service code: ";
        cin >> servcode;
        i++;
        if (i == 3)
        {
            cout << "\n" << "Too many invalid attempts, program terminating." << "\n"
             << "Have a nice day. " << "\n" << "\n";
            exit (0);
        } //end if
    } //end while
    cout << "\n" << "You entered: " << servcode << "\n"
     << "Is that correct? [y,n]";
    cin >> serviceyn;
  } while (serviceyn != 'y'); // end do/while loop

  return servcode;
}
```

Comment: A canonical question is *[Multiple conditions in a C 'for' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859029/)*. But there must be one from 2008 or 2009.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
while (servcode != 'R' && servcode != 'P' && i < 3)
```

Note the expanded comparison and the removal of the semicolon at the end:

1. `(servcode != 'R', 'P')` is valid C++ but doesn't do what you're expecting it to do;
2. the semicolon makes the statement into a loop with an empty body, so it continues executing forever since the loop condition never changes.

Comment: so thats why the server stopped my program, i created a never ending/never changing loop that was using up resources?

Comment: is that a basic buffer overflow attack or am i thinking of somehting else?

Comment: @SamLaManna: No, it's not a buffer overflow. The extraneous semicolon makes the loop into an infinite one, since nether `servcode` nor `i` ever change.

Comment: ok thanks, just making sure im not in danger of breaking somehting

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
while ((servcode != 'R', 'P') && (i < 3));
```

to:

```
while ((servcode != 'R') && (servcode != 'P') && (i < 3))
```

Note the removal of an unwanted semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

```
(servcode != 'R', 'P')
```

Should be:

```
(servcode != 'R') && (servcode != 'P')
```

Kudos to PaulR for correction. My brain is not in gear.

Comment: No - it needs to be `&&`, not `||`.

Comment: PaulR: Correction, yes. Ampersands required. Not ors.

Comment: @PaulR: You were correct. Loop logic is indeed inverse to if-statement logic ( if(servcode == 'R' || servcode == 'P') versus (servcode != 'R' && servcode != 'P') ).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
while(something != 'a' && something != 'b')
```

You're using the comma operator, which discards the results of every expression except the last, so this:

```
while(something != 'a', 'b')
```

Will compare `something` with `a`, ignore the result, and use `'b'` as the condition of the loop. `'b'` is a non-zero value, so it's always true and the loop goes on forever (or until memory runs out, or something else stops it).

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down this statement and see what it's doing. I've put in some extra punctuation that does not change the meaning of the statement.

```
while (((servcode != 'R'), ('P')) && (i < 3)) { };
```

The comma operator separates two different expressions and returns the value of the second one. The first part probably does what you expect, but the second part is just a literal character 'P' which is always true!

The semicolon at the end of the statement marks the body of what will be executed as the while loop. It's a do-nothing which does not change the value of `servcode` or `i`, so obviously once you enter the loop you will never leave it. This is a common mistake.