# Multiple conditions in 'for' loop in C

Tags: c, string, for-loop, substring

I am trying to find a substring in a string. While doing this, I understood that to check for multiple conditions in a `for` loop if we write

```
for(i=0; condition1, condition2; i++)
```

the value of `condition1` is found and then discarded. Then, the value of `condition2` is found and returned. To get around this, we need to use `&&` in case of multiple conditions to be checked by a `for` loop in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17638730/are-multiple-conditions-allowed-in-a-for-loop).

```
for(i=0; condition1 && condition2; i++)
```

So far I believe I understood right, but the following `for` loop is not working.

```
for(i=0; (a[i] != '\0') && (a[i] == b[0]); i++)
{
    j = i + 1;
    k = 1;
    while(a[j] == b[k] && a[j] != '\0' && b[k] != '\0')
    {
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    if(b[k] == '\0')
    {
        return i;
    }
}
return -1;
```

When I wrote the above `for` loop, the control is entering the loop and performing the operations, whereas in the following code, control is not even entering the `for` loop, and it is working correctly.

```
for(i=0; a[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
  if(a[i] == b[0])
  {
      j = i + 1;
      k = 1;
      while(a[j] == b[k] && a[j] != '\0' && b[k] != '\0')
      {
          j++;
          k++;
      }
      if(b[k] == '\0')
      {
          return i;
      }
  }
}
```

Is there something I am missing about internal processing in `for` loops? I believe the way they both should work is the same.

Comment: A canonical question is *[Multiple conditions in a C 'for' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859029/)*. But there must be one from 2008 or 2009.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **first** code snippet your `for` loop has two conditions. Remember when one of them is not true, the loop will terminate immediately.

In the **second** code snippet, you just have one condition in the `for` loop. The second condition is inside an `if` case. So `if` condition2 is wrong the `if` case won't be executed, but the `for` loop will still continue.

Comment: damn, i didn't know how i missed logic of that simple @RomCoo. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

These blocks of code don't do the same thing. In the first one, if either condition isn't met then the *for* loop will stop iterating. In the second block, if the first condition isn't met, then the *for* loop will stop iterating, whereas if the second one isn't met the internal code isn't executed, but the *for* loop will continue.

As for the && operator.... It will evaluate all of the conditions *in order* and it will stop and evaluate to false as soon as it hits an individual component that evaluates to false. If it doesn't run into any false condition then it will evaluate to true.