# Weird output of merge sort for no. of entries not being a power of 2. - c

Tags: c, sorting, mergesort

I have written a code for mergesort to sort an array of structures in c it works fine when i give no. of entries as a power of 2 but does not even sort the records for other no. of entries. ***I Would like to learn where is my logic going wrong??***

Here is my code:

```
void Mergesort(struct record r[],int n)
{
    int k;
    if(n>1)
    {
        int i,j;
        struct record r1[n/2];
        struct record r2[n-n/2];
        for(i=0,j=n/2;i<n/2 && j<n;i++,j++)
        {
            r1[i]=r[i];
            r2[i]=r[j];
        }
        Mergesort(r1,n/2);
        Mergesort(r2,n/2);
        r=Merge(r1,r2,r,n);
    }

}

struct record * Merge(struct record r1[],struct record r2[],struct record r[],int n)
{
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    while(i<n/2 && j<n/2)
    {
        if (strcmp(r1[i].a,r2[j].a)<=0)
        {
            r[k]=r1[i];
            i=i+1;
        }
        else
        {
            r[k]=r2[j];
            j=j+1;
        }
        k=k+1;
    }
    if(i==n/2)
    {
        for(j;j<n/2 && k<n;j++,k++)
        {
            r[k]=r2[j];
        }

    }
    else
    {
        for(i;i<n/2 && k<n;i++,k++)
        {
            r[k]=r1[i];
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.!!

```
Sample Input for 8 entries:

CS003 Vinay 10
CS005 Mouli 9.94
CS010 Gautham 9.94
CS020 Sneha 9.94
CS200 Mohit 9.93
CS012 Aarti 9.9
CS002 Adithya 9.78
CS001 Adithya 9.58

Getting correct output as follows:

CS012 Aarti 9.90
CS002 Adithya 9.78
CS001 Adithya 9.58
CS010 Gautham 9.94
CS200 Mohit 9.93
CS005 Mouli 9.94
CS020 Sneha 9.94
CS003 Vinay 10.00
**[Sorted according to the Names in the record]**

Sample input for 7 entries:

CS003 Vinay 10
CS005 Mouli 9.94
CS010 Gautham 9.94
CS020 Sneha 9.94
CS200 Mohit 9.93
CS012 Aarti 9.9
CS002 Adithya 9.78

Output(Weird):

CS200 Mohit 9.93
CS005 Mouli 9.94
CS020 Sneha 9.94
CS012 Aarti 9.90
CS003 Vinay 10.00
CS010 Gautham 9.94
CS002 Adithya 9.78

[Not at all sorted according to the names]
```

Comment: Isn;t the same question got posted a while ago?

Comment: Code in the Question is same but the problem is different!!! Previously it was segmentation fault. It got fixed with the help from u programmers. Now a new problem has occurred and i was advised to put up a new question for it.

Comment: check my answer. this should fix your code

Comment: Not working!!! Now even for entries of power of 2 its giving random output. Also can u tell me that what would be the condition for k in the loop in the merge function, as n is not identified in that function!

Comment: i checked with the sample input i have given for 8 & 7 entries, now its not working for either of them. :(  **Its giving repeated entries, any idea why??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the below changes:

```
void Mergesort(struct record r[],int n)
{
    int k;
    if(n>1)
    {
        int i,j;
        struct record r1[n/2];
        struct record r2[n-n/2];
        for(i=0; i<n/2; i++)
        {
            r1[i]=r[i];
        }
        for(i=0,j=n/2; j < n; i++,j++) // This is required because your previous logic used to skip the last element of j when n is odd.
        {
            r2[i]=r[j];
        }
        Mergesort(r1,n/2);
        Mergesort(r2,n-n/2);//this is 'n - n/2'
        r=Merge(r1,r2,r,n/2, n-n/2); //The sizes are different so pass both
    }

}

struct record * Merge(struct record r1[],struct record r2[],struct record r[],int r1N, int r2N)
{
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    while(i<r1N && j<r2N)
    {
        if (strcmp(r1[i].a, r2[j].a)<=0)
        {
            r[k]=r1[i];
            i=i+1;
        }
        else
        {
            r[k]=r2[j];
            j=j+1;
        }
        k=k+1;
    }
    if(i==r1N)
    {
        for(j;j< r2N && k < (r1N + r2N);j++,k++)
        {
            r[k]=r2[j];
        }

    }
    else
    {
        for(i;i < r1N && k < (r1N+r2N); i++,k++)
        {
            r[k] = r1[i];
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Not working!!! Now even for entries of power of 2 its giving random output. Also can u tell me that what would be the condition for k in the loop  in the merge function, as n is not identified in that function!

Comment: n should be r1N + r2N. Updated in answer as well

Comment: i checked with the sample input i have given for 8 & 7 entries, now its not working for either of them. :(  **Its giving repeated entries, any idea why??**

Comment: Thanks for considering..!! Looking forward to it.

Comment: did you update the value of n in Merge function and check (i.,e, r1N + r2N)

Comment: am on chat, you can reply there. I have posted you a question there

Comment: Testing for `k < (r1N+r2N)` is unnecessary, as `k` is increased together either with `i` or with `j`. And the limits for `i` and `j` come from dividing `n` into 'halves' `r1N` and `r2N`, so `k` may reach that sum *only* together with `i==r1N && j==r2N` (unless the code is broken).

Comment: Yes, I agree. It is not required for this case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this loop:

```
for(i=0,j=n/2;i<n/2 && j<n;i++,j++) { ... }
```

Since you are filling `r1[]` and `r2[]` in the same loop, you are filling each array with the same number of items. However, if `n` is an odd number, you will need to put the last remaining element of `r[]` into one of these arrays. The easiest solution would be to have two separate loops.

Answer (score 1):

Your main mistake is

- not considering unequal 'halves' of `n` in case of odd value, which means your code works only if all divisions of `n`-s by halves produce even numbers (until it went down to 2=1+1); that implies **the starting value of `n` must be a power of 2.**

That is reflected in following errors:

- a single `for()` loop to fill both `r1[]` and `r2[]` despite the fact they are different lengths;
- the recursive call to `Mergesort` with `r2` passing wrong length (`n/2` while it should be `n-n/2`);
- passing the `n` parameter alone to `Merge` and *not calculating* `n-n/2` for `r2[]` inside `Merge`.

In addition, unused variable `k` declared in `Mergesort` and useless `r` assignment at the end of the function.

Please see the code below.

```
void Mergesort(struct record r[], int n)
{
    if (n > 1)
    {
        int n1 = n/2;
        int n2 = n - n1;
        int i;
        struct record r1[n1];
        struct record r2[n2];

        for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)    // fill r1[] with n1 items from r[]
            r1[i] = r[i];
        for (i = 0; i < n2; i++)    // fill r2[] with n2 items from r[]
            r2[i] = r[n1+i];        // skipping n1 already copied to r1[]

        Mergesort(r1, n1);          // pass appropriate lengths
        Mergesort(r2, n2);
        Merge(r1, r2, r, n1, n2);   // pass arrays with lengths
    }
}

void Merge(struct record r1[], struct record r2[], struct record r[], int n1, int n2)
{
    int i=0, j=0, k=0;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2)        // any items left in both sub-arrays?
    {
        if (strcmp(r1[i].a, r2[j].a) <= 0)  // append the smaller one
            r[k++] = r1[i++];               // or earlier if they're equal
        else
            r[k++] = r2[j++];
    }

    while (i < n1)                  // append the remaining part, if any
        r[k++] = r1[i++];
    while (j < n2)
        r[k++] = r2[j++];
}
```

You might also simplify the code a bit by dropping indices and operating directly on pointers and decrementing lengths of remaining parts:

```
void Merge(struct record r1[], struct record r2[], struct record r[], int n1, int n2)
{
    while (n1 && n2)        // any items left in both sub-arrays?
    {
        if (strcmp(r1->a, r2->a) <= 0)  // append the smaller one
            *r++ = *r1++, n1--;         // or earlier if they're equal
        else
            *r++ = *r2++, n2--;
    }

    while (n1--)                  // append the remaining part, if any
        *r++ = *r1++;
    while (n2--)
        *r++ = *r2++;
}
```