# how to input two conditions in a For Loop?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, conditional-statements, cs50

I want to create a condition so that blank will not turn negative due to the blank -=1.
For example if n = 3, blank = 1 therefore will print two "#", however I want it to stop at 0 when it loops

Here's my code

```
for (int blank = n-2; blank < n; blank -=1) 
    printf("#");
printf("\n");
```

something like this is what i'm trying to achieve

```
for (int blank = n-2; blank < n or blank > 0; blank -=1) 
    printf("#");
printf("\n");
```

or

```
for (int blank = n-2; blank < n; blank -=1) 
printf("#");
    {
        if (blank == 0) break;
    }
    printf("\n");
```

thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple conditions in a C 'for' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859029/multiple-conditions-in-a-c-for-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used "or" in your pseudocode, but you really want to loop while `blank` is less `n` *and* while `blank` is greater than `0`. `&&` is the logical-and operator, so you could use the following:

```
for (int blank = n-2; blank < n && blank > 0; blank -= 1)
```

But `blank < n` is always true, so you can simply use the following:

```
for (int blank = n-2; blank > 0; blank -= 1)
```

---

Note that `i -= 1` can be written `--i` for integer types.

```
for (int blank = n-2; blank > 0; --blank)     # blank goes from n-2 to 1
```

This would produce the same outcome:

```
for (int blank = n-2; blank-- > 0; )          # blank goes from n-3 to 0
```

If `n` was guaranteed to be at least `2`, you could also use a common idiom:

```
for (int blank = n-2; blank--; )              # blank goes from n-3 to 0 if n>=2
```

Comment: thank you!, you're right, it was an "and"/"&&" I needed. Life saver, I can sleep now

Answer (score 0):

Just use a logical OR

blank < n or blank > 0 can be represented as:

(blank < n) || (blank > 0)

Comment: Should be `blank < n && blank > 0`. Actually, it should be just `blank > 0`.