# Multiple conditions in 'for' loop for a single loop in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, logical-operators

I came through this code snippet while I was referring to C++ multiple-choice questions. Previously I used only && or || for combining multiple conditions, but this code uses ',':

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < 0, 5; i++)
       printf("%d ", i);
   return 0;
}
```

Formally, the answer for this one is an infinite loop. What is the working of this snippet? How are the conditions getting evaluated?

Comment: That's the comma operator. Also, `using namespace std` isn't C

Comment: @Spikatrix right i edited that .. mistook it as it came in  c mcqs...Btw thankyou!

Comment: What is the intent of this snippet?  What are 'the conditions'? (i between zero and 5?)

Comment: A canonical question is *[Multiple conditions in a C 'for' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859029/)*. But there must be one from 2008 or 2009.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a comma operator in the condition of your for loop. The [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) evaluates its first operand and discards the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns this value (and type). The comma operator also has the lowest precedence of all C/C++ operators, meaning it's always the last one to bind to an expression.

So the condition in your for loop is equivalent to:

```
(i < 0), 5
```

The result of this expression is always 5, which is not 0 (false). Hence the condition is always true.

If you leave loop running for long enough eventually `i`, which is a signed integer, will overflow. This results in undefined behaviour (thanks @Jarod42).

Comment: Or in other words, Since the for loop conditional check uses the comma operator it will allows evaluate ```(i <0 ) ``` first then ```5``` second resulting in the condition always being true because the expression ```5``` is always true, therefore infinite loop.

Comment: @Mike: not infinite loop, UB with signed overflow of `i`.

Comment: @Jarod42 then ans should be undefined behaviour-depends on compiler .. right??

Comment: @gyaneshsharma: your snippet exhibits UB.

Answer (score 0):

In function 'int main()':

> 10:16: warning: left operand of comma operator has no effect [-Wunused-value]

Run your code [here](http://cpp.sh/) and read the warnings.